# Improve pronounciation of a model

Tags: pytorch, text-to-speech, phoneme

I fine-tuned a dataset of [Nvidia Tacotron2](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2). While working reasonably well, there are some mispronounciations of words(I train a german dataset).

I have another set of wave files by the same speaker with according metadata.csv

How do I filter this to include mainly those sentences that teach the model the very pronounciations that are missing?